# How do I start with a clean Star System world on a new dedicated server?

Tags: space-engineers

I've just set up a new dedicated server for my friends and I to play with.

But when I log into the server there's already a medical room belonging to "First Colonist" and even if you select "No Faction" it still insists on dropping you into a massive, sprawling, fully kitted out base complete with a fleet of prebuilt ships.

Literally taking all of the fun out of a game about building stuff by simply building it all for you. If I wanted a game to play itself, I'd just watch YouTube videos.

No matter what settings I tinker with, no matter how many times I generate a new world, this prebuilt base is always there.  How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I was having, which I document here just in case anyone else comes along trying to figure out the same problem, is that the dedicated server for Space Engineers seems to re-write its own config file whenever the server is shut down.  This results in many of the changes you made to the config file being erased.

The procedure, which is poorly documented, is to stop the server entirely. Then make changes to the config files. Then start the server up again. "Restart" will never work.